# Can I send an email to multiple users using SendGrid?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I have an eventhubtriggered azure function the code is below

```
public class Function {

    @FunctionName("ehprocessor")
    public void eventHubProcessor(
            @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "", connection = "eventhubConnString", dataType = "string", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE) String eventHubMessage,
            @SendGridOutput(name = "message", dataType = "String", apiKey = "sendGridAPIKey", to = "jithinvariyarmv@gmail.com", from = "jithin@vinnovatelabz.com", subject = "Azure Functions email with SendGrid", text = "Sent from Azure Functions") OutputBinding<String> message,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        final String toAddress = "jithinvariyarmv@gmail.com";
        final String value = "Sent from Azure Functions-->" + eventHubMessage;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder().append("{")
                .append("\"personalizations\": [{ \"to\": [{ \"email\": \"%s\"}]}],")
                .append("\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"%s\"}]").append("}");

        final String body = String.format(builder.toString(), toAddress, value);

        message.setValue(body);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have used @SendGridOutput annotation and inside that I have from and to email addresses. The function.json generated is as shown below

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "../eventfunction-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "dk.scanomat.coffeecloud.eventfunction.Function.eventHubProcessor",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "eventHubTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "msg",
    "dataType" : "string",
    "connection" : "eventhubConnString",
    "eventHubName" : "",
    "cardinality" : "ONE"
  }, {
    "type" : "sendGrid",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "message",
    "apiKey" : "sendGridAPIKey",
    "subject" : "Azure Functions email with SendGrid",
    "dataType" : "String",
    "from" : "jithin@vinnovatelabz.com",
    "to" : "jithinvariyarmv@gmail.com",
    "text" : "Sent from Azure Functions"
  } ]
}
```

So there is only one receiver for this email. Is there any way to send the same email to multiple users?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage that using the *`Personalization`*

```
var personalization = new Personalization();
personalization.AddBcc(new Email("mark@test.com"));  
personalization.AddTo(new Email("bob@test.com"));
```